# How to receive data on android activity from other xml file(not another activity)?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext

I have an android activity having IncomeActivity.java and activity_income.xml and then i created a xml file named activity_loginincome.xml(not any android activity). 
Then, in IncomeActivity.java, i have used alert dialog in which i have included activity_loginincome.xml interface and positive button(for login) and negative button(for cancel) by using following code:(I HAVE ALSO WRITTEN IN COMMENT BELOW FOR TWO LINES WHERE ERROR OCCURS AND FOR EDITTEXT FROM WHICH I WANT TO GET DATA AND TO BE SHOWN ON TOAST VIEW )

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aa();   
        }
    });
```

private void aa()
    {

```
    final EditText user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1Log); **//THIS IS THE EDITTEXT FROM WHICH I WANT TO GET DATA SO AS TO BE SHOWN ON TOAST VIEW**
    final View addView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_loginincome, null); /* HERE IS THE ACTIVITY_LOGININCOME.XML INCLUDED */
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Enter the following")
    .setView(addView)
    .setPositiveButton("Login",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



            String usr=user.getText().toString(); **//IF I REMOVE THIS LINE THEN APP RUNS NOWMALLY OTHERWISE IT GETS STOPPED**
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Data entered is :  "+usr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
    .show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the `EditText` with ID `e1Log` is in `activity_loginincome.xml`. If that is true, then when you do this:

```
final EditText user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1Log);
```

variable `user` will contain null, since these is no `View` in your activity's content view that has the ID `e1Log`.

To fix this you need to find the `EditText` in the inflated View AFTER you inflate `activity_loginincome.xml`, like this:

```
// Inflate the view for the Dialog
final View addView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_loginincome, null);
// Locate the EditText in the inflated View
final EditText user = (EditText)addView.findViewById(R.id.e1Log);
```